# return all fields for Project using workfront-api and python

Tags: python, workfront-api

How can *all* of the fields be displayed for 'Project' using the `workfront-api` in Python?  The examples below return the default fields, but `fields=*` and `fields=All` return syntax errors.

Examples using the `Workfront` examples in `api.py` and `test.py` that work:

```
results = client.search(ObjCode.PROJECT,{'groupID':user.homeGroupID})
results = client.search(ObjCode.PROJECT,{'groupID':user.homeGroupID},fields=None)
```

Answer (score 0):

`fields='*'` or `fields=['*']` should work just fine.

`results = client.search(ObjCode.PROJECT,{'groupID':user.homeGroupID},fields=['*'])`

It won't return collections or references. For that, you would need something like this:

`results = client.search(ObjCode.PROJECT,{'groupID':user.homeGroupID},fields=['*','owner:*'])`

Comment: How do you read custom field values that are returned to a variable?  In the example above if I had a custom field in project called "Custom Field"  I understand I can search it by saying 
results = client.search(ObjCode.PROJECT,{'groupID':user.homeGroupID},fields=['DE:Custom Field'])

How would I the  read the value of the custom field?

Comment: The value should just return as a key/value pair in the JSON result. For example {'ID":'ABC123', 'DE:Custom Field':'My Custom Form Data Value Here'}